# can we use global on a varibale defined in a method?

Tags: tkinter, global, python-3.6

wrongcounter =0

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
#the algebra questions
question_of_alge_levels = {             '1' : 'Solve g - 8 = 16?' ,
                                        '2' : 'Solve x - 56 = 23?' ,
                                        '3' : 'Enter 3x / 3 = 3?' ,
                                        '4' : 'Enter 10x / 5 = 40?' ,
                                        '5' : 'Enter 70x + 100 = 240?' ,
                                        '6' : 'Enter 95x + 130 =320',
                                        '7' : 'Enter 4x + 32 + 52 = 163' ,
                                        '8' : 'Enter 4(2a+3)=-3(a-1)+31',
                                        '9' : 'Enter 5(7a+5)=-3(a-2)+42',
                                        '10': '12(9a+5)=-10(a-4)+48?',
                                        '11':'You Have Finished You Are a Genius Panther:)'
                                          }  
#the answers of algebra questions                      
anwser_of_alge_levels = {              '1' : '24' ,
                                       '2' : '79' ,
                                       '3' : '3' ,
                                       '4' : '20' ,
                                       '5' : '2'  ,
                                       '6' : '2' ,
                                       '7' : '19.75' ,
                                       '8' : '2' ,
                                       '9' : '0.60' ,
                                      '10' : '0.23',
                                      '11' : '{Pha<n>tex}'
                                      }
```

I grouped this window into a method so that i could bind it into my button 
so this button can be clicked and display the new window.

```
root = Tk()




          #Algebra Section
#the algebra window grouped into a method
def algebra(a):
         #declaring the level as 1
        level = 1
         #our window(window)

        window = Tk()
         #Algebra Answer entry
        Alge_answerbox = ttk.Entry(window)
        Alge_answerbox.grid(row = 2 , column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
               #algebra label
        Alge_Question = ttk.Label(window , text=question_of_alge_levels[str(level)],font = 'times 10 bold')
        Alge_Question.grid(row = 1, column = 0 , sticky = 'we')
              #something that not 

              #submit button  
        #the submit button inside of the algebra window

        alge_submit = ttk.Button(window  , text= 'Submit x')
        alge_submit.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = 'we')
        #binding the submit button so the answer is checked when clicked

        alge_submit.bind('<Button-1>' , algebra_method)
        #the numberwrong 
        alge_NumberWrong = ttk.Label(window , text = 'Number Incorrect : 0')
        alge_NumberWrong.pack()
        root.withdraw()
```

Here is where the problem come in at ,I can not get the value of the entry `Alge_answerbox` even though it is defined as global , im not sure if this is logical , if not , could you guide me to another solution so the `algebra_method` can get the value of the entry `Alge_answerbox`, and use its data

```
def algebra_method(a):


    level = 1
    global Alge_answerbox
    global wrongcounter

    #checking to see if the answer is wrong          
    while True:

        if Alge_answerbox.get() != anwser_of_alge_levels[str(level)]:
            wrongcounter +=1
            alge_NumberWrong.configure(text ='Number Incorrect: ' + str(wrongcounter))
        break
    #checking to see if the answer is right               
    while True :
        if Alge_answerbox.get()  == anwser_of_alge_levels[str(level)]:
                        #if true increment the level by 1
                           level =level + 1
                        #update the question because the level has changed
                           Alge_Question.configure(text = question_of_alge_levels[str(level)])
                        #update the displayed level because the level has changed
                           Alge_levellabel.configure(text = 'Level : '+ str(level))

                           Alge_answerbox.delete(0 , 'end')
button = ttk.Button(root ,text = 'click')
button.pack()
#binding the algebra window into this button
button.bind('<Button-1>' , algebra)
#constantly looping through our main window 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: BTW: in dictionary you can use numers instead of strings as keys `{ 1:"question1" }` and then you don't have to use `str(level)`. But you could use list `["question1", ...]` and still use number as index/key. You cound even keep it as pairs `[ ("question1", "answer1"), (..., ...), ...]` and read it from `csv` file

Comment: Yea I know I could've used ints , but I just thought it looked better as a string , kinda a preference , but I got to get into the habbit of writing short and   concise code so I'll keep that in consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `global Alge_answerbox` inside wherever it is first defined as well. As in you need to put it in your `algebra` function before assigning it to an object:

```
def algebra(a):

    global Alge_answerbox, Alge_Question, level
    #declaring the level as 1
    level = 1

    #our window(window)
    window = Tk()
    ...
```

Also similarly you need to declare `Alge_Question` and `level` as `global` as well.